# Program is losing an increment and two ``printf``s

Tags: java, c, assembly, java-native-interface, intel-tsx

In the method below, we set `volatile int success = 0` and then enter a

`while(!success)` loop.

The loop increments `tries`, then enters a transaction, from within which we make a call to java `sun.misc.Unsafe.putLong` and we keep looping until the transaction succeeds.

so long as the debug flag `__TRX_DEBUG__` is set, it will print the number of tries before returning.

Since that number is consistently zero, I have since added some "Hello" `printf`s.

The output of the program is

> Hello0?!
>
> putLong: (Lsun/misc/Unsafe;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V with 0 tries

And I quite simply don't understand why.

```
/*
* Class:     jnirtm_Transactionally
* Method:    putLong
* Signature: (Lsun/misc/Unsafe;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V
*/
jmethodID midPutLong = NULL;
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_jnirtm_Transactionally_putLong__Lsun_misc_Unsafe_2Ljava_lang_Class_2Ljava_lang_Object_2JJ(
    JNIEnv *env,
    jclass _obsolete,
    jobject unsafe,
    jclass unsafe_class,
    jobject base,
    jlong off,
    jlong value
){
    if(midPutLong == NULL){
        midPutLong = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,unsafe_class,"putLong","(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V");
        #ifdef __TRX_ASSERT__
        assert(midPutLong != NULL);
        #endif
    }
    
    volatile int tries = 0;
    volatile int success = 0;
    while(!success){/*TODO: maybe switch to a different strategy when tries grows too large?*/
        printf("Hello0?!\n");
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "incl %0\n"
            "xbegin 1f" /*1f: local label 1, look forward to find first*/
                :"+rm"(tries)
                :"rm"(success)/*artificial dependency to prevent re-ordering*/
        );

        /*do we need more artificial dependencies, here, to avoid re-ordering?*/

        //unsafe.putInt(base,off,value);
        printf("Hello1?!\n");
        (*env)-> CallVoidMethod(env,unsafe,midPutLong,base,off,value);
        printf("Hello2?!\n");

        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "xend\n\t"
            "incl %0\n" /*increment success ==> break out of loop*/
            "jmp 2f\n" /*jump to end of loop*/
            "1:\n" /*local label 1 (jumped to when transaction is aborted)*/
            "2:" /*local label 2 (jumped to after a successfully completed transaction)*/
            :"+rm"(success)
            :"rm"(tries) /*artificial dependency*/
        );
    }
    #ifdef __TRX_DEBUG__
        printf("putLong: (Lsun/misc/Unsafe;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V with %d tries\n",tries);
    #endif
}
```

The interesting thing is that further up the file, I have a different method,

```
/*
* Class:     jnirtm_Transactionally
* Method:    putLong
* Signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;J)V
*/
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_jnirtm_Transactionally_putLong__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_String_2J(JNIEnv* env, jclass _obsolete, jobject target, jstring fieldname, jlong value){
    jclass targetClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,target);
    
    const char *str_fname = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env,fieldname,NULL);
    jfieldID fidFLD = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, targetClass, str_fname, "J");

    volatile int tries = 0;
    volatile int success = 0;
    while(!success){/*TODO: maybe switch to a different strategy when tries grows too large?*/
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "incl %0\n"
            "xbegin 1f" /*1f: local label 1, look forward to find first*/
                :"+rm"(tries)
                :"rm"(success)/*artificial dependency to prevent re-ordering*/
        );

        /*do we need more artificial dependencies, here, to avoid re-ordering?*/

        (*env)->SetLongField(env,targetClass,fidFLD,value);

        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "xend\n\t"
            "incl %0\n" /*increment success ==> break out of loop*/
            "jmp 2f\n" /*jump to end of loop*/
            "1:\n" /*local label 1 (jumped to when transaction is aborted)*/
            "2:" /*local label 2 (jumped to after a successfully completed transaction)*/
            :"+rm"(success)
            :"rm"(tries) /*artificial dependency*/
        );
    }
    #ifdef __TRX_DEBUG__
        printf("putLong: (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;J)V with %d tries\n",tries);
    #endif
}
```

which does essentially the same (except it's using a different method to change the data), but which consistently outputs

> putLong: (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;J)V with 1 tries

Each method gets called exactly once per run (from Java):

```
    //requires base class acquisition and field index lookup
    Transactionally.putLong(base$x, "x",3L);
    assert(data.x == 3);

    //requires callback to java which then invokes intrinsics
    Transactionally.putLong(Transactionally.unsafe, Transactionally.unsafe_class, base$x, off$x, 4L);
    assert(data.x == 4);
```

and that the program is running without throwing an assertion error is just adding to my confusion.

Because if `assert(data.x == 4)` does no throw an error, then

```
(*env)-> CallVoidMethod(env,unsafe,midPutLong,base,off,value);
```

in the first C method must have succeeded.
Yet it succeeded without executing the increment to `tries` before it started the transaction, nor did it execute the two `printf`s I inserted around it.

**UPDATE**
Adding the `printf`s to the second method will also not print them. So I guess being in a transaction suppresses IO and the behaviour is different only for the `tries` counter.

Why is this happening and how do I stop it?

**UPDATE**

Removed the hello printfs and wasn't sure how to create the asm code directly, so I instead disassembled the resulting `.so` file.

Zooming in on the parts that matter,

this is from the working method:

```
    while(!success){/*TODO: maybe switch to a different strategy when tries grows too large?*/
867:    eb 41                   jmp    8aa <Java_jnirtm_Transactionally_putLong__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_String_2J+0xda>
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
869:    8b 45 e4                mov    -0x1c(%rbp),%eax
86c:    8b 55 e0                mov    -0x20(%rbp),%edx
86f:    ff c2                   inc    %edx
871:    c7 f8 30 00 00 00       xbeginq 8a7 <Java_jnirtm_Transactionally_putLong__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_String_2J+0xd7>
877:    89 55 e0                mov    %edx,-0x20(%rbp)
                :"rm"(success)/*artificial dependency to prevent re-ordering*/
        );

        /*do we need more artificial dependencies, here, to avoid re-ordering?*/

        (*env)->SetLongField(env,targetClass,fidFLD,value);

        [...]

8aa:    8b 45 e4                mov    -0x1c(%rbp),%eax
8ad:    85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
8af:    74 b8                   je     869 <Java_jnirtm_Transactionally_putLong__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_String_2J+0x99>
```

And this is from the faulty method:

```
   while(!success){/*TODO: maybe switch to a different strategy when tries grows too large?*/
968:    eb 5b                   jmp    9c5 <Java_jnirtm_Transactionally_putLong__Lsun_misc_Unsafe_2Ljava_lang_Class_2Ljava_lang_Object_2JJ+0xfb>
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
96a:    8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
96d:    8b 55 f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%edx
970:    ff c2                   inc    %edx
972:    c7 f8 4a 00 00 00       xbeginq 9c2 <Java_jnirtm_Transactionally_putLong__Lsun_misc_Unsafe_2Ljava_lang_Class_2Ljava_lang_Object_2JJ+0xf8>
978:    89 55 f8                mov    %edx,-0x8(%rbp)
        );

        /*do we need more artificial dependencies, here, to avoid re-ordering?*/

        //unsafe.putLong(base,off,value);
        (*env)-> CallVoidMethod(env,unsafe,midPutLong,base,off,value);

        [...]

9c5:    8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
9c8:    85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
9ca:    74 9e                   je     96a <Java_jnirtm_Transactionally_putLong__Lsun_misc_Unsafe_2Ljava_lang_Class_2Ljava_lang_Object_2JJ+0xa0>
```

I still don't see any relevant difference that would explain the behaviour.

**Full Objdump**

```
lib/libRTM_transact.so:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .init:

0000000000000670 <_init>:
670:    48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
674:    48 8b 05 5d 09 20 00    mov    0x20095d(%rip),%rax        # 200fd8 <__gmon_start__>
67b:    48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
67e:    74 02                   je     682 <_init+0x12>
680:    ff d0                   callq  *%rax
682:    48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
686:    c3                      retq   

Disassembly of section .plt:

0000000000000690 <.plt>:
690:    ff 35 72 09 20 00       pushq  0x200972(%rip)        # 201008 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x8>
696:    ff 25 74 09 20 00       jmpq   *0x200974(%rip)        # 201010 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x10>
69c:    0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)

00000000000006a0 <printf@plt>:
6a0:    ff 25 72 09 20 00       jmpq   *0x200972(%rip)        # 201018 <printf@GLIBC_2.2.5>
6a6:    68 00 00 00 00          pushq  $0x0
6ab:    e9 e0 ff ff ff          jmpq   690 <.plt>

00000000000006b0 <__assert_fail@plt>:
6b0:    ff 25 6a 09 20 00       jmpq   *0x20096a(%rip)        # 201020 <__assert_fail@GLIBC_2.2.5>
6b6:    68 01 00 00 00          pushq  $0x1
6bb:    e9 d0 ff ff ff          jmpq   690 <.plt>

Disassembly of section .plt.got:

00000000000006c0 <.plt.got>:
6c0:    ff 25 32 09 20 00       jmpq   *0x200932(%rip)        # 200ff8 <__cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5>
6c6:    66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000000006d0 <deregister_tm_clones>:
6d0:    48 8d 3d 59 09 20 00    lea    0x200959(%rip),%rdi        # 201030 <_edata>
6d7:    48 8d 05 59 09 20 00    lea    0x200959(%rip),%rax        # 201037 <_edata+0x7>
6de:    55                      push   %rbp
6df:    48 29 f8                sub    %rdi,%rax
6e2:    48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
6e5:    48 83 f8 0e             cmp    $0xe,%rax
6e9:    76 15                   jbe    700 <deregister_tm_clones+0x30>
6eb:    48 8b 05 de 08 20 00    mov    0x2008de(%rip),%rax        # 200fd0 <_ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable>
6f2:    48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
6f5:    74 09                   je     700 <deregister_tm_clones+0x30>
6f7:    5d                      pop    %rbp
6f8:    ff e0                   jmpq   *%rax
6fa:    66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
700:    5d                      pop    %rbp
701:    c3                      retq   
702:    0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
706:    66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
70d:    00 00 00 

0000000000000710 <register_tm_clones>:
710:    48 8d 3d 19 09 20 00    lea    0x200919(%rip),%rdi        # 201030 <_edata>
717:    48 8d 35 12 09 20 00    lea    0x200912(%rip),%rsi        # 201030 <_edata>
71e:    55                      push   %rbp
71f:    48 29 fe                sub    %rdi,%rsi
722:    48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
725:    48 c1 fe 03             sar    $0x3,%rsi
729:    48 89 f0                mov    %rsi,%rax
72c:    48 c1 e8 3f             shr    $0x3f,%rax
730:    48 01 c6                add    %rax,%rsi
733:    48 d1 fe                sar    %rsi
736:    74 18                   je     750 <register_tm_clones+0x40>
738:    48 8b 05 b1 08 20 00    mov    0x2008b1(%rip),%rax        # 200ff0 <_ITM_registerTMCloneTable>
73f:    48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
742:    74 0c                   je     750 <register_tm_clones+0x40>
744:    5d                      pop    %rbp
745:    ff e0                   jmpq   *%rax
747:    66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
74e:    00 00 
750:    5d                      pop    %rbp
751:    c3                      retq   
752:    0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
756:    66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
75d:    00 00 00 

0000000000000760 <__do_global_dtors_aux>:
760:    80 3d c9 08 20 00 00    cmpb   $0x0,0x2008c9(%rip)        # 201030 <_edata>
767:    75 27                   jne    790 <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x30>
769:    48 83 3d 87 08 20 00    cmpq   $0x0,0x200887(%rip)        # 200ff8 <__cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5>
770:    00 
771:    55                      push   %rbp
772:    48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
775:    74 0c                   je     783 <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x23>
777:    48 8b 3d aa 08 20 00    mov    0x2008aa(%rip),%rdi        # 201028 <__dso_handle>
77e:    e8 3d ff ff ff          callq  6c0 <.plt.got>
783:    e8 48 ff ff ff          callq  6d0 <deregister_tm_clones>
788:    5d                      pop    %rbp
789:    c6 05 a0 08 20 00 01    movb   $0x1,0x2008a0(%rip)        # 201030 <_edata>
790:    f3 c3                   repz retq 
792:    0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
796:    66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
79d:    00 00 00 

00000000000007a0 <frame_dummy>:
7a0:    48 8d 3d 61 06 20 00    lea    0x200661(%rip),%rdi        # 200e08 <__JCR_END__>
7a7:    48 83 3f 00             cmpq   $0x0,(%rdi)
7ab:    75 0b                   jne    7b8 <frame_dummy+0x18>
7ad:    e9 5e ff ff ff          jmpq   710 <register_tm_clones>
7b2:    66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
7b8:    48 8b 05 29 08 20 00    mov    0x200829(%rip),%rax        # 200fe8 <_Jv_RegisterClasses>
7bf:    48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
7c2:    74 e9                   je     7ad <frame_dummy+0xd>
7c4:    55                      push   %rbp
7c5:    48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
7c8:    ff d0                   callq  *%rax
7ca:    5d                      pop    %rbp
7cb:    e9 40 ff ff ff          jmpq   710 <register_tm_clones>

00000000000007d0 <Java_jnirtm_Transactionally_putLong__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_String_2J>:
/*
* Class:     jnirtm_Transactionally
* Method:    putLong
* Signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;J)V
*/
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_jnirtm_Transactionally_putLong__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_String_2J(JNIEnv* env, jclass _obsolete, jobject target, jstring fieldname, jlong value){
7d0:    55                      push   %rbp
7d1:    48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
7d4:    48 83 ec 50             sub    $0x50,%rsp
7d8:    48 89 7d d8             mov    %rdi,-0x28(%rbp)
7dc:    48 89 75 d0             mov    %rsi,-0x30(%rbp)
7e0:    48 89 55 c8             mov    %rdx,-0x38(%rbp)
7e4:    48 89 4d c0             mov    %rcx,-0x40(%rbp)
7e8:    4c 89 45 b8             mov    %r8,-0x48(%rbp)
    jclass targetClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,target);
7ec:    48 8b 45 d8             mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rax
7f0:    48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
7f3:    48 8b 80 f8 00 00 00    mov    0xf8(%rax),%rax
7fa:    48 8b 4d c8             mov    -0x38(%rbp),%rcx
7fe:    48 8b 55 d8             mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rdx
802:    48 89 ce                mov    %rcx,%rsi
805:    48 89 d7                mov    %rdx,%rdi
808:    ff d0                   callq  *%rax
80a:    48 89 45 e8             mov    %rax,-0x18(%rbp)
    
    const char *str_fname = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env,fieldname,NULL);
80e:    48 8b 45 d8             mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rax
812:    48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
815:    48 8b 80 48 05 00 00    mov    0x548(%rax),%rax
81c:    48 8b 75 c0             mov    -0x40(%rbp),%rsi
820:    48 8b 4d d8             mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rcx
824:    ba 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edx
829:    48 89 cf                mov    %rcx,%rdi
82c:    ff d0                   callq  *%rax
82e:    48 89 45 f0             mov    %rax,-0x10(%rbp)
    jfieldID fidFLD = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, targetClass, str_fname, "J");
832:    48 8b 45 d8             mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rax
836:    48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
839:    48 8b 80 f0 02 00 00    mov    0x2f0(%rax),%rax
840:    48 8b 55 f0             mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rdx
844:    48 8b 75 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rsi
848:    48 8b 7d d8             mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rdi
84c:    48 8d 0d ad 01 00 00    lea    0x1ad(%rip),%rcx        # a00 <_fini+0x18>
853:    ff d0                   callq  *%rax
855:    48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)

    volatile int tries = 0;
859:    c7 45 e0 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x20(%rbp)
    volatile int success = 0;
860:    c7 45 e4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x1c(%rbp)
    while(!success){/*TODO: maybe switch to a different strategy when tries grows too large?*/
867:    eb 41                   jmp    8aa <Java_jnirtm_Transactionally_putLong__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_String_2J+0xda>
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
869:    8b 45 e4                mov    -0x1c(%rbp),%eax
86c:    8b 55 e0                mov    -0x20(%rbp),%edx
86f:    ff c2                   inc    %edx
871:    c7 f8 30 00 00 00       xbeginq 8a7 <Java_jnirtm_Transactionally_putLong__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_String_2J+0xd7>
877:    89 55 e0                mov    %edx,-0x20(%rbp)
                :"rm"(success)/*artificial dependency to prevent re-ordering*/
        );

        /*do we need more artificial dependencies, here, to avoid re-ordering?*/

        (*env)->SetLongField(env,targetClass,fidFLD,value);
87a:    48 8b 45 d8             mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rax
87e:    48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
881:    48 8b 80 70 03 00 00    mov    0x370(%rax),%rax
888:    48 8b 4d b8             mov    -0x48(%rbp),%rcx
88c:    48 8b 55 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdx
890:    48 8b 75 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rsi
894:    48 8b 7d d8             mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rdi
898:    ff d0                   callq  *%rax

        __asm__ __volatile__ (
89a:    8b 45 e0                mov    -0x20(%rbp),%eax
89d:    8b 55 e4                mov    -0x1c(%rbp),%edx
8a0:    0f 01 d5                xend   
8a3:    ff c2                   inc    %edx
8a5:    eb 00                   jmp    8a7 <Java_jnirtm_Transactionally_putLong__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_String_2J+0xd7>
8a7:    89 55 e4                mov    %edx,-0x1c(%rbp)
    while(!success){/*TODO: maybe switch to a different strategy when tries grows too large?*/
8aa:    8b 45 e4                mov    -0x1c(%rbp),%eax
8ad:    85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
8af:    74 b8                   je     869 <Java_jnirtm_Transactionally_putLong__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_String_2J+0x99>
            :"+rm"(success)
            :"rm"(tries) /*artificial dependency*/
        );
    }
    #ifdef __TRX_DEBUG__
        printf("putLong: (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;J)V with %d tries\n",tries);
8b1:    8b 45 e0                mov    -0x20(%rbp),%eax
8b4:    89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
8b6:    48 8d 3d 4b 01 00 00    lea    0x14b(%rip),%rdi        # a08 <_fini+0x20>
8bd:    b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
8c2:    e8 d9 fd ff ff          callq  6a0 <printf@plt>
    #endif
}
8c7:    90                      nop
8c8:    c9                      leaveq 
8c9:    c3                      retq   

00000000000008ca <Java_jnirtm_Transactionally_putLong__Lsun_misc_Unsafe_2Ljava_lang_Class_2Ljava_lang_Object_2JJ>:
    jobject unsafe,
    jclass unsafe_class,
    jobject base,
    jlong off,
    jlong value
){
8ca:    55                      push   %rbp
8cb:    48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
8ce:    48 83 ec 40             sub    $0x40,%rsp
8d2:    48 89 7d e8             mov    %rdi,-0x18(%rbp)
8d6:    48 89 75 e0             mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
8da:    48 89 55 d8             mov    %rdx,-0x28(%rbp)
8de:    48 89 4d d0             mov    %rcx,-0x30(%rbp)
8e2:    4c 89 45 c8             mov    %r8,-0x38(%rbp)
8e6:    4c 89 4d c0             mov    %r9,-0x40(%rbp)
    if(midPutLong == NULL){
8ea:    48 8b 05 ef 06 20 00    mov    0x2006ef(%rip),%rax        # 200fe0 <midPutLong@@Base-0x58>
8f1:    48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
8f4:    48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
8f7:    75 61                   jne    95a <Java_jnirtm_Transactionally_putLong__Lsun_misc_Unsafe_2Ljava_lang_Class_2Ljava_lang_Object_2JJ+0x90>
        midPutLong = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,unsafe_class,"putLong","(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V");
8f9:    48 8b 45 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
8fd:    48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
900:    48 8b 80 08 01 00 00    mov    0x108(%rax),%rax
907:    48 8b 75 d0             mov    -0x30(%rbp),%rsi
90b:    48 8b 7d e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rdi
90f:    48 8d 0d 33 01 00 00    lea    0x133(%rip),%rcx        # a49 <_fini+0x61>
916:    48 8d 15 44 01 00 00    lea    0x144(%rip),%rdx        # a61 <_fini+0x79>
91d:    ff d0                   callq  *%rax
91f:    48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
922:    48 8b 05 b7 06 20 00    mov    0x2006b7(%rip),%rax        # 200fe0 <midPutLong@@Base-0x58>
929:    48 89 10                mov    %rdx,(%rax)
        #ifdef __TRX_ASSERT__
        assert(midPutLong != NULL);
92c:    48 8b 05 ad 06 20 00    mov    0x2006ad(%rip),%rax        # 200fe0 <midPutLong@@Base-0x58>
933:    48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
936:    48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
939:    75 1f                   jne    95a <Java_jnirtm_Transactionally_putLong__Lsun_misc_Unsafe_2Ljava_lang_Class_2Ljava_lang_Object_2JJ+0x90>
93b:    48 8d 0d be 01 00 00    lea    0x1be(%rip),%rcx        # b00 <__PRETTY_FUNCTION__.3410>
942:    ba 43 00 00 00          mov    $0x43,%edx
947:    48 8d 35 1b 01 00 00    lea    0x11b(%rip),%rsi        # a69 <_fini+0x81>
94e:    48 8d 3d 2d 01 00 00    lea    0x12d(%rip),%rdi        # a82 <_fini+0x9a>
955:    e8 56 fd ff ff          callq  6b0 <__assert_fail@plt>
        #endif
    }
    
    volatile int tries = 0;
95a:    c7 45 f8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
    volatile int success = 0;
961:    c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
    while(!success){/*TODO: maybe switch to a different strategy when tries grows too large?*/
968:    eb 5b                   jmp    9c5 <Java_jnirtm_Transactionally_putLong__Lsun_misc_Unsafe_2Ljava_lang_Class_2Ljava_lang_Object_2JJ+0xfb>
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
96a:    8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
96d:    8b 55 f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%edx
970:    ff c2                   inc    %edx
972:    c7 f8 4a 00 00 00       xbeginq 9c2 <Java_jnirtm_Transactionally_putLong__Lsun_misc_Unsafe_2Ljava_lang_Class_2Ljava_lang_Object_2JJ+0xf8>
978:    89 55 f8                mov    %edx,-0x8(%rbp)
        );

        /*do we need more artificial dependencies, here, to avoid re-ordering?*/

        //unsafe.putInt(base,off,value);
        (*env)-> CallVoidMethod(env,unsafe,midPutLong,base,off,value);
97b:    48 8b 45 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
97f:    48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
982:    4c 8b 90 e8 01 00 00    mov    0x1e8(%rax),%r10
989:    48 8b 05 50 06 20 00    mov    0x200650(%rip),%rax        # 200fe0 <midPutLong@@Base-0x58>
990:    48 8b 10                mov    (%rax),%rdx
993:    48 8b 7d c0             mov    -0x40(%rbp),%rdi
997:    48 8b 4d c8             mov    -0x38(%rbp),%rcx
99b:    48 8b 75 d8             mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rsi
99f:    48 8b 45 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
9a3:    4c 8b 4d 10             mov    0x10(%rbp),%r9
9a7:    49 89 f8                mov    %rdi,%r8
9aa:    48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
9ad:    b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
9b2:    41 ff d2                callq  *%r10

        __asm__ __volatile__ (
9b5:    8b 45 f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
9b8:    8b 55 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%edx
9bb:    0f 01 d5                xend   
9be:    ff c2                   inc    %edx
9c0:    eb 00                   jmp    9c2 <Java_jnirtm_Transactionally_putLong__Lsun_misc_Unsafe_2Ljava_lang_Class_2Ljava_lang_Object_2JJ+0xf8>
9c2:    89 55 fc                mov    %edx,-0x4(%rbp)
    while(!success){/*TODO: maybe switch to a different strategy when tries grows too large?*/
9c5:    8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
9c8:    85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
9ca:    74 9e                   je     96a <Java_jnirtm_Transactionally_putLong__Lsun_misc_Unsafe_2Ljava_lang_Class_2Ljava_lang_Object_2JJ+0xa0>
            :"+rm"(success)
            :"rm"(tries) /*artificial dependency*/
        );
    }
    #ifdef __TRX_DEBUG__
        printf("putLong: (Lsun/misc/Unsafe;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V with %d tries\n",tries);
9cc:    8b 45 f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
9cf:    89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
9d1:    48 8d 3d c0 00 00 00    lea    0xc0(%rip),%rdi        # a98 <_fini+0xb0>
9d8:    b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
9dd:    e8 be fc ff ff          callq  6a0 <printf@plt>
    #endif
}
9e2:    90                      nop
9e3:    c9                      leaveq 
9e4:    c3                      retq   

Disassembly of section .fini:

00000000000009e8 <_fini>:
9e8:    48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
9ec:    48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
9f0:    c3                      retq
```

Comment: This is a little bit of apples and oranges comparison. You don't have the `printf("Hello...")` statements in your second example, so it's hard to tell whether it is indeed behaving differently. In your first example, if you comment out the `asm` section right after the print of "Hello0" does it go on to print "Hello1"`?

Comment: @lurker it does indeed. (note that I need to comment out both ASM sections because an ``xend`` without a corresponding ``xbegin`` will crash the application. You're right, though, if I add the hello printfs to the other method, they don't get printed either. Will update the question. What doesn't change, though, is the different behaviour for the ``tries`` counter.

Comment: I wonder if they are not getting printed because of some issue with flushing the output buffers. If after *every* `printf` you do `fflush(stdout)` what happens?

Answer (score 2):

No I/O can be performed can be performed in a transaction so the `printf` calls will likely abort the transaction. Then control passes to the `1:` label, this is undefined behaviour as jumps between `asm` statements are not allowed, and `eax` is modified without being listed in the clobber or output lists.

The target of `xbegin` needs to be in the same `asm` statement or be a C label referenced using the `asm` `goto` extension. Or better use the intrinsics and avoid inline assembly.

Comment: Intrinsics of course would be the best way assuming your version of the compiler (4.8.x+) is new enough to support them.